# Regex: how to capture all content before next matching pattern (or end of file)

Tags: regex, font-awesome, pcre

I am trying to process [icons.yml](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/6b4fd47b620aec8978b8486a8eed7ab4039d4c80/src/icons.yml) (from the [FontAwesome](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome)-project) with regular expressions. (Language is "[Dyalog APL](http://dyalog.com)" which uses the PCRE-Library. I am setting flags there for "case insensitive" and "dot matches lines breaks".)
So, with the following input:

```
  - name:       Glass
    id:         glass
    unicode:    f000
    created:    1.0
    categories:
      - Web Application Icons
      - Test1
      - Test2

  - name:       Music
    id:         music
    unicode:    f001
    created:    1.0
    categories:
      - Web Application Icons

  - name:       Search
    id:         search
    unicode:    f002
    created:    1.0
    categories:
      - Web Application Icons
```

I am looking for a rx that would give me the content of "`name`", "`id`", "`unicode`", "`created`" and finally "`categories`" (where I need all content before the next "- name" starts or EOF).

Have successfully put together an expressions that returns the first 4, but fails for "categories". Somehow this "*EOF or not "-name"*" gives me mental overflow ;-)

```
.*-\sname:\s*([a-z\-]*)\s*id:\s*([a-z\-]*)\s*unicode:\s*([0-9a-f]{4})\s*created:\s*([0-9\.]*)\s*categories:\s*((?!-\sname:))
```

Comment: I don't know what programming language you are using, but usually you must also treat the newlines in your text. And as a suggestion into capturing the categories, take a look on the look-ahead regex.

Comment: I would also suggest you some improvements in the regex `[a-z\-]`. This will capture only lower-case characters. Maybe you want to try the `\w` instead of `[a-z]`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I added a sentence about the environment to clarify. Will switch to `\w`

Comment: @MBaas I have edited my answer,  can you have look into it ?

Comment: Thanks - I am just testing it... ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
name:(.*?)id:(.*?)unicode:(.*?)created:(.*?)categories:(.*?)(?=- name|$)
```

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/lMSpe7/10)

Perl Sample:

```
   #!/usr/bin/perl
# your code goes here

use strict;

my $str = '- name:      Glass
id:         glass
unicode:    f000
created:    1.0
categories:
  - Web Application Icons
  - Test1
  - Test2

- name:       Music
id:         music
unicode:    f001
created:    1.0
categories:
  - Web Application Icons

- name:       Search
id:         search
unicode:    f002
created:    1.0
categories:
  - Web Application Icons1
';
my $regex = qr/name:(.*?)id:(.*?)unicode:(.*?)created:(.*?)categories:(.*?)(?=- name|$)/sp;

while ( $str =~ /$regex/g ) {
  print "Whole match is ${^MATCH}\n";

}
```

[Run the code here](http://ideone.com/pPwW7K)